# How can design using pure css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float, css-transitions

[image]

This is the image I want to design using pure css without background image, can use background color. Any suggestion me to do design for above mentioned image.

Comment: Tell us what you've dons so far. Don't expect us to write a solution for you...

Comment: 'without background image' - I assume you are allowed to use CSS background with gradients? Have a go and if you get stuck put your code into your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't have many reputations to comment on, i.e. I'm replying to you in the answer. I'm a newbie.

You have to research more on this content, you should search "Pure Css Posters" on youtube for reference.
For now, I would suggest you some ideas.

1. You can use 2 sections to create those white blocks, and For Shape Just use the "clip-path" Property and for the card container, put a gradient on the background using linear-gradient.

2. In those white sections, use before or after selectors to mark that greyish part.

3. Make sure you're using Flex properties to keep it aligned.